# Fourier transform on finite groups in characteristic $p>0$

Tags: finite-groups, fourier-transform, positive-characteristic, modular-representation-theory

Is there a Fourier theory for finite groups in characteristic $p>0$? Assume that $p$ divides the order $|G|$ of finite groups (or just work with $p$-groups), i.e., in a modular representation-theoretic setting.

If no such full theory, maybe just for abelian case? Thank you for any relevant references.

Comment: It might help if you described what you might expect or hope for from such a theory..  There are orthogonality relations due to Brauer for modular characters.

Comment: Using the Brauer character table one can express any class function defined just on the $p'$-classes (i.e. the conjugacy classes of elements of order not divisible by $p$) as a linear combination of irreducible characters. In the abelian case this isn't much more than the complex character theory applied to the subgroup of $p'$-elements. For general class functions there just aren't enough irreducible characters to go around. Geoff Robinson has mentioned orthogonality relations: these involve projective characters and might serve as a partial substitute.

Comment: @GeoffRobinson In fact I am looking for some kind of fast Fourier transform with coefficients in characteristic $p$, but I don't know how exactly Fourier transform is formulated in char $p$. Since it involves modular representations, I would like to know what the dual side should be, which is no longer the same as in ordinary case.

Comment: @MarkWildon Exactly, in general there will be not enough irreducible characters. I'm not familiar with modular representation theory, my naive guess is that the dual side of Fourier transform should include irreducible and indecomposable representations, but I don't know if that makes sense...

Comment: I don't know exactly what you mean by Fourier theory, but the analogue of Pontyagin duality for finite commutative group schemes is Cartier duality: $G^\vee = \mathbf{Hom}(G,\mathbf G_{\operatorname{m}})$. The dual of the discrete group $\mathbf Z/p$ is the nonreduced local group scheme $\pmb\mu_p = \operatorname{Spec} k[x]/(x^p-1)$, so you'll probably have to leave the world of abstract groups.

Comment: @R.vanDobbendeBruyn Yes I know Cartier duality. I expect Fourier transform in char $p$ to envolve finite group schemes, though I still don't know what it is like, even in abelian case.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a brief outline of the modular theory developed by R. Brauer : First of all, is necessary to take complex valued class functions. Then (after certain choices of prime ideal containing the rational prime $p$, etc. ), there are $m$ irreducible Brauer characters $\{\phi_{i}: 1 \leq i \leq m \}$, where $G$ has $m$ conjugacy classes of $p$-regular elements. There is a "dual basis" of Brauer characters of projective indecomposable modules $\{ \Phi_i : 1 \leq i \leq m \}$. Any complex valued class-function $\psi$ defined only on $p$-regular elements is uniquely expressible in the form $\sum_{i = 1}^{m} \langle \psi, \Phi_{i} \rangle \phi_{i}$, where for two complex valued class functions $\alpha, \beta$ defined only on $p$-regular elements, we define
$\langle \alpha, \beta \rangle $ to be the complex number $|G|^{-1}\sum_{g \in G_{p^{\prime}}} \alpha(g) \beta(g^{-1})$, where $G_{p^{\prime}}$ is the set of $p$-regular $g \in G$.

Each $\phi_{i}$ is obtained from an irreducible representation $\sigma_{i}$ of $G$ over an algebraically closed field $F$ of characteristic $p$. For $g \in G$ of order prime to $p$, $\phi_{i}(g)$ is obtained by lifting the eigenvalues to $g$ in that representation to $p^{\prime}$-roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}$ in a consistent fashion and adding them.

Each $\Phi_{i}$ is defined in an analogous manner, except that we must use the projective cover (as $FG$-module) of the irreducible module associated to $\sigma_{i}$. It is the case that we always have $\langle \phi_{i}, \Phi_{j} \rangle = \delta_{i,j}$ for $1 \leq i,j \leq m$.

It is worth remarking that if we try to do this for a prime $p$ which does not divide $|G|$, then we find that $\phi_{i} = \Phi_{i}$ for each $i$, and that the $\phi_{i}$ obtained are just the complex irreducible characters of $G$ (and all elements of $G$ are $p$-regular in this case). This is essentially because all $FG$-modules are projective when $p$ does not divide $|G|$.

Comment: Thank you for the outline! It seems Brauer's theory won't say much if there are no $p$-regular elements, e.g. for $p$-groups, is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, more or less, except that the identity is always a $p$-regular element. You might want to look at things like Burnside Rings instead of character rings, depending on what you are looking for.